# How to suppress caption numbering in a figwindow

Tags: captions

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figwindow}[1,l,{\mbox{%
\includegraphics[width=80pt]{g/tiger.png}}},{\label{fig:leadfield}\TeX{} Tiger}]

In this lab, you will record the standard limb leads in sequence,according to the diagram below:
The goal for the Frank electrode system is to capture the three-dimensional extent of the heart dipole.  For this, it is necessary to measure potential differences not just in the frontal plane, as in the limb leads, but along the antero-posterior (front-to-back) axis of the body.  The diagram below illustrates the original Frank lead system \cite{RSM:Fra56} and we will use a simplified version of this.
\end{figwindow}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own `figwindownonum` environment that doesn't set the caption using the `figure` type. Instead, it just prints whatever you pass it:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{picinpar}% http://ctan.org/pkg/picinpar
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\makeatletter
\long\def\figwindownonum[#1,#2,#3,#4] {% \begin{figwindownonum}
  \begin{window}[#1,#2,{#3},{\centering#4\par}] }
\def\endfigwindownonum{\end{window}}% \end{figwindownonum}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{figwindownonum}[1,l,{\mbox{%
\includegraphics[width=80pt]{tiger}}},{\TeX{} Tiger}]
In this lab, you will record the standard limb leads in sequence,according to the diagram below:
The goal for the Frank electrode system is to capture the three-dimensional extent of the heart dipole.  For this, it is necessary to measure potential differences not just in the frontal plane, as in the limb leads, but along the antero-posterior (front-to-back) axis of the body.  The diagram below illustrates the original Frank lead system and we will use a simplified version of this.
In this lab, you will record the standard limb leads in sequence,according to the diagram below:
The goal for the Frank electrode system is to capture the three-dimensional extent of the heart dipole.  For this, it is necessary to measure potential differences not just in the frontal plane, as in the limb leads, but along the antero-posterior (front-to-back) axis of the body.  The diagram below illustrates the original Frank lead system and we will use a simplified version of this.
\end{figwindownonum}

\end{document}
```

You could also consider using the [`wrapfig` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig). Here's a small example that somewhat duplicates your usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{85pt}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=80pt]{tiger} \par
  \TeX{} Tiger
\end{wrapfigure}
In this lab, you will record the standard limb leads in sequence,according to the diagram below:
The goal for the Frank electrode system is to capture the three-dimensional extent of the heart dipole.  For this, it is necessary to measure potential differences not just in the frontal plane, as in the limb leads, but along the antero-posterior (front-to-back) axis of the body.  The diagram below illustrates the original Frank lead system and we will use a simplified version of this.
In this lab, you will record the standard limb leads in sequence,according to the diagram below:
The goal for the Frank electrode system is to capture the three-dimensional extent of the heart dipole.  For this, it is necessary to measure potential differences not just in the frontal plane, as in the limb leads, but along the antero-posterior (front-to-back) axis of the body.  The diagram below illustrates the original Frank lead system and we will use a simplified version of this.


\end{document}
```

Comment: You can mention (as an argument in favor of `wrapfig` or any other replacement) the note by Piet van Oostrum in the [CTAN edition entry for `picinpar`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/picinpar.html)